# Uncaught (in promise) error happens randomly when trying to use innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Hi I get this error when trying to change html content via innerHTML 
the error doesn't occur first attempt but after that

error message:

```
admin.js:61 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (admin.js:61)
(anonymous) @   admin.js:61
async function (async)      
(anonymous)
```

here is the code :

```
const edit = async (btn) => {
    const res = await fetch(`admin/products/edit/${btn.getAttribute('id')}`)
    let product = await res.json()

    if (product) {
        $('#edit-product-modal').modal('show')
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#edit-product-modal [name]')).forEach((elm) => {
            for (let i of Object.keys(product)) {
                if (elm.getAttribute('name') === i) elm.value = product[i]
            }
        })
    }

    document.querySelector('#edit-product-modal').addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.target.querySelector('.btn').disabled = true

        const data = { _id: null, name: null, price: null, dprice: null, description: null }

        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#edit-product-modal [name]')).forEach((elm) => {
            for (let i of Object.keys(data)) {
                if (elm.getAttribute('name') === i) data[i] = elm.value
            }
        })

        const res = await fetch(`admin/products/edit/${btn.getAttribute('id')}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })

        const product = await res.json()

        btn.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = productHtml(product) //the error happens here
        e.target.querySelector('.btn').disabled = false
        $('.modal').modal('hide')

    })
}
```

Comment: When your code changes parent element html structure it have to care about keeping the correct  html structure of  original one with slight changes that you need. In opposite case your html layout becomes broken and query selectors find nothing after  first innerHtml correction.

Comment: hmm any ideas to solve this case?

Comment: actually the functionality still works but the error occurs which mean it is not broken I am really confused why this happens

Comment: it relates of what your code add as innerHtml content. Error means that  btn element  loses parent.parent element after first innerHtml  substitution. It might not contain btn element at all. Could you provide your initial html layout and  html result of  productHtml(product) generation ?

Comment: const productHtml = (product) => {
    return `
     <tr>
        <td>${product.name}</td>
        <td>${product.price}</td>
        <td>${product.date}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-product-modal"
             id="${product._id}" onclick="edit(this)">Edit</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger" id="${product._id}" onclick="remove(this)">Del</button></td> 
    </tr>
    `
}

Comment: If I have understood correct and generated code should substitute row in table  You should  remove <tr>  tag from your code generation due to inner html  is added with your   code exactly to <tr> tag (it is parent of parent of your save button) and additional <tr> tag inside already existed breaks html layout

Comment: yea but that bug actually does nothing to the layout for some reason I have checked the html there is only one <tr> . and as I said there is no problem with layout it is just the error and some lag

Comment: browsers could resolve this issue themselves with  different own's manner. Also could you provide original html before first substitution?

Comment: the table body is fed dynamically but it is gonna look something like this 
https://pastebin.com/t5Nzwyay

Comment: the problem is gone when I changed "btn" for direct querySelector on the button .
I don't really know the cause of that yet

Comment: I have suspicions that `this` for dynamic added content  might be slight different then for regular one. but anyway it is good job

Comment: ok,thanks god here is the real problem : every time I use submit event listeners stack . the solution is to remove them after every event here is the real solution https://pastebin.com/XEVVgg3e

Comment: Yes without full html layout it was tricky to determine that model container is outside of replaced html content. Yes each call "edit" function  adds the same event to submit event handler.